# React native HTML entities

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, entity

I'm fetching some data in app from WordPress site successfully. Some entities like "&#8222" react native don't want to make like quotes and many more issues I have.

Is there some way to make HTML entities right in React Native App?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to use something like [html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities) to decode the text before rendering:

```
const entities = new Entities();
entities.decode('&#8222') // "„" (double low quotation mark)
```

Comment: I did install the package in my React Native project. I import using `import Entities from 'html-entities'` and put `const entities = new Entities(); entities.decode('&#xf169;');` in `render() { ... }` but it returns 'undefined is not a constructor'. Could you explain the steps?

Comment: @JeafGilbert I think you're importing it in an incompatible way. See the README for html-entities for examples of how you can import what you need.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.  This is the way I solved it:

First of all install html-entities :

npm install html-entities

In your code :

```
import {decode} from 'html-entities';

console.log(decode(stringToBeDecoded));
```

Comment: For what it's worth to future readers, this is the one which worked for me. Importing Html5Entities as a constructor per the other answers didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to import and use a specific subpackage of Entities if the example in 'html-entities' README, which uses require(), won't work for you.

```
import {Html5Entities} from 'html-entities';

const entities = new Html5Entities();
entities.decode(stringToBeDecoded);
```

Comment: Import was helpful to a React Native noobie like me. For anyone else looking, install the packet using `npm install html-entities` or `yarn add html-entities`