# How do I convert special characters like: &quot; into chracters like: " with JS?

Tags: javascript, string, formatting

I found these string things (idk what to call them) from a json database and I noticed that it was writing those letters instead of the actual character. I undestand why, but I can't figure out how to convert it to a normal character. I have tried searching online but I didn't find anything.

Another of me seeing this is instead of ', I get

```
&#039;
```

I tried searching online and through Stack Overflow and I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those things are called [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity). Here's kind of a hcky solution to convert them using a helper element:

```js
const helper = document.createElement("div")
helper.innerHTML = "potato&amp;tomato" // set HTML content with entity
console.log(helper.innerText) // read "rendered" content
```

Comment: I tried using this but it gave me the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document`. I think it is because I am using React Native for mobile apps and not HTML for web

Comment: @KeeryelTett Oooooh I see in that case I would use a 3rd party library; check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390486 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241281